# NavigationStack and NavigationDestination, using NavigationPath Correctly passing data

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I am trying to pass data from one View to another using `@StateObject` navigating using `NavigationStack` and `NavigationPath`. In my case I can't use `NavigationLink`.

[image]

To achieve that a came up with this code:

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var inputValue: String = ""
    @StateObject private var dataStore = DataStore()
    @StateObject var coordinator = Coordinator()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $coordinator.path) {
            VStack {
                TextField("Enter a value", text: $inputValue)
                    .padding()
                
                Button("Next") {
                    dataStore.stringValue = inputValue
                    coordinator.gotoNext()
                }
                .padding()

            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Destination.self) { destination in
                switch destination {
                case .ContentView:
                    ContentView()
                case .NextView:
                    NextView()
                }
            }
            .environmentObject(coordinator)
        }
    }
}
```

The first View

```
struct NextView: View {
    @StateObject private var dataStore = DataStore()
    @EnvironmentObject var coordinator: Coordinator
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text("Value from previous view:")
                    .padding()
                Text(dataStore.stringValue)
                    .padding()
                Button {
                    coordinator.gotoHomePage()
                } label: {
                    Text("Back to home page")
                }
            }
        
    }
}
```

The second View

```
class Coordinator: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path = NavigationPath()
    
    func gotoHomePage() {
        print("Go to Home")
        path.removeLast(path.count)
    }
    
    func gotoNext() {
        print("gotoNext")
        path.append(Destination.NextView)
    }
    
    func goBack() {
        print("goBack")
        path.removeLast()
    }
}
```

The Coordinator (NavigationPath)

```
class DataStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var stringValue: String = ""
}

enum Destination {
    case ContentView
    case NextView
}
```

Data Structure and navigation

When I run the code, I can navigate forward (to the `NextView`, but no values appears and when I try to get back to the `ContentView`, the code crashs.

Looks like there aren't data in de `enviroment` neither `DataStore` are holding value.

What I'm doing wrong?

** **Update 1**

When I move the environment set to the App struct then the code works fine:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct NavigationStackApp: App {
    @StateObject var dataStore = DataStore()
    @StateObject var coordinator = Coordinator()
    private var root = ContentView()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(coordinator)
                .environmentObject(dataStore)
        }
    }
}
```

** **Update 2**

So If I want to do this from a `view struct` instead of `App struct` I should create an `mainView` to set the environment and encapsulate the first view that will use the environment objects:

```
struct MainView:View {
    @StateObject var dataStore = DataStore()
    @StateObject var coordinator = Coordinator()
    var body: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(coordinator)
            .environmentObject(dataStore)
    }
}
```

Comment: The data stores have no connection to each other

Comment: You should not have `@StateObject private var dataStore = DataStore()` in your `NextView` and `ContentView` etc...
use `@EnvironmentObject var dataStore: DataStore` in those views.
You should have only **one** `@StateObject private var dataStore = DataStore()` (in your `NavigationStackApp`) that you pass around using the `.environmentObject(dataStore)`.